# jQuery slideToggle only working on one div, and not others

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I have a simple tab navigation system set up, and I wanted to code it to be cleaner and more modular.

I made a JSFiddle for you to try it out.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-4">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li id="tab_entry"      value="0"   class="navActive myPanelNavLi"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span> Entry</li>
            <li id="tab_search"     value="1"   class="myPanelNavLi">Search</li>
        </ul>
   </nav>

<div class="panelTab_0 myPanelActive lightShadow darkBg roundedBottom">
STORAGE ENTRY
</div>

<div class="panelTab_1 myPanelActive lightShadow darkBg roundedBottom">
STORAGE ENTRY
</div>
```

JS:

```
    //myPanel sliders
$(".myPanelNavLi").click(function(){

    var choiceValue = $(this).attr("value");
    var choice = '.panelTab_' + choiceValue;
    console.log(choice);

    $(this).parent().parent().next(choice).slideToggle(300);

});
```

Basically, when you click "Entry" it slide toggles properly,

But when you click Search, it doesn't slide. This is has been driving me crazy. Any help is greatly appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/g44xt4m8/3/

Thank you.
Nick

Comment: Please 1. use stack exchange fiddles, 2. remove all irrelevant code, and 3. tidy up your format. If you do so, I'll commit to helping you :)

Comment: The code I posted is about as clean as I could get it. If you're going to complain about something that minor, I'd rather wait on someone else. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try https://jsfiddle.net/g44xt4m8/5/

```
$(".myPanelNavLi").click(function(){

        var choiceValue = $(this).attr("value");
        var choice = '.panelTab_' + choiceValue;

        $(choice).slideToggle(300);


    });
```

Comment: Although this works, it doesnt work for what I want it to do. I'm making pages that have a lot of these panels, and as such, they need to find the correct panel internally instead of searching the entire document via $.("x"). Can you see the error in my code as to why its not working the way I currently have it set up?

Comment: Fixed it; I changed .next() to .siblings().